# What is button property "tooltip" used for?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm writing a test application to try out what QML has to offer. I have created a simple button and tried to create a tooltip on mouse hover event. I found several solutions already how to make that happen ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874663/delay-of-tooltip-dissapear-in-qml)) and it is not a problem.

In the documentation, however, I have encountered a button property called `tooltip`. Now I assumed if a built-in component has such a property then creation of tooltip is automated. Apparently that is not the case, since defining `tooltip` property did not change anything.

The question is what is this property actually used for?

```
Button {
    id: myButton
    x: 10
    y: 10
    text: "Click me"
    tooltip: "Some tooltip"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Showing of tooltip requires receiving of mouse hover events and this is possible only if your button is not overlapped with some another `MouseArea` with `hoverEnabled` property equal to `true`. Following example shows tooltip fine on OS X and Qt 5.2.1:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello World"
    }
    Button {
        id: myButton
        x: 10
        y: 10
        text: "Click me"
        tooltip: "Some tooltip"
    }
}
```